# Trying to get Button text when Implementing onClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm pretty new at android so I hope I don't sound too noobie, That being said I made a fragment that implements an OnclickListener specifically for buttons that are in my XML. I need the default onclick function to be able to save the text of the button that is pressed to a string but I haven't been able to figure out how to retrieve the button's text from the view. This would help me from making an if statement for every single button I will make. Any suggestions?

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class Section1Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Section1Fragment";

    Button btnItem1;
    Button btnItem2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section1,container,false);

        btnItem1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnItem1);
        btnItem1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnItem2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnItem2);
        btnItem2.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnItem1) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("button 1")
                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
        else if (view == btnItem2) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("button 2")
                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263673/get-text-of-view-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text of view (button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263673/get-text-of-view-button)

Answer (score 0):

**view.getText().toString()** is what you need to call to get the text value of a view. Here's the sample code.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnItem1) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), btnItem1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("button 1")
                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    else if (view == btnItem2) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), btnItem1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("button 2")
                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you want to correctly declare the button, so go into the xml file, and make sure but button has an ID. You can add an ID by doing the following in the button: `android:id="@+id/button"`

Then in the Java code file, you want to declare it like this:

```js
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
```

That should work, so then you want to make the listener, which can be done this way:

```js
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View _v) {
    //what you want button to do
  }
});
```